# Splitting column from one record into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following customer data in SQL Server 2008:

Table name `Customer_Note`:

| Note_ID | Customer_ID | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | This is a note I am adding to the record and its a very long record indeed |
| 2 | 102 | Note 2 |

I would like to update the the `Note` column from `Note_ID = 1` where the first 20 rows remain in `Note_ID = 1` and then do an insert into new rows where the rest of the note is split into new rows with 20 character note columns without impacting `Note_ID = 2`, so for example I now want to see:

| Note_ID | Customer_ID | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | This is a note I am |
| 2 | 102 | Note 2 |
| 3 | 99 | adding to the record |
| 4 | 99 | and its a very lon |
| 5 | 99 | g record indeed |

Comment: `the first 20 records` do you mean first 20 characters ?

Comment: sorry yes first 20 characters

Answer (score 0):

I think substring works on 2008 but don't hold me to it. dbfiddle.uk only goes back to 2014.

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/LBd2JtER)

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0
DECLARE @t TABLE (Note_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Customer_ID INT, Note VARCHAR(200))

WHILE @i < (SELECT MAX(LEN(NOTE)) FROM data)
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t
    SELECT Customer_ID
         , SUBSTRING(Note, @i, 20) Note 
      FROM data
     WHERE SUBSTRING(Note, @i, 20) <> ''
  SET @i = @i + 20 
END

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Answer (score 0):

See section B here.  ***This logic only works on SQL Server 2016 or later.***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

This code is using CROSS APPLY and a function to split the string.  However, I did not increment Note_ID since I don't want to complicate it in order to simplify the logic.  This will keep Note_ID the same for new records.

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Note(Note_ID, Customer_ID, Note)
SELECT Note_ID, Customer_ID, value  
FROM Customer_Note
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitIntoFixedLengthString(Note, 20)
WHERE Note_ID = 1
```

If Note_ID was auto incrementing, you could simply remove the column.  This will avoid Note_ID = 2.

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Note(Customer_ID, Note)
SELECT Customer_ID, value  
FROM Customer_Note
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitIntoFixedLengthString(Note, 20)
WHERE Note_ID = 1
```

Table based function:

```
create function dbo.SplitIntoFixedLengthString (@string nvarchar(max), @stringlength int) 
returns @list table (string nvarchar(max)) as begin if len(@string) > 0 and @stringlength > 0  
    begin
      declare @i 
      int set @i = 1
      while @i <= len(@string)   
      begin    
        insert into @list (string) select SUBSTRING(@string,@i,@stringlength)    
        set @i = @i + @stringlength   end
      end
      return    
    end
```

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/05/03/sql-server-fix-error-invalid-object-name-string_split/

Answer (score 0):

You can split the long string by joining to a tally table (`numbers`) and use `substring()` to extract every 20 characters.

As you need to update back the original plus inserting new rows to the table, you can do it in one go using `merge`

```
declare @max_len int = 20,
        @last_id int

select @last_id = max(Note_ID) from Customer_Note;

with numbers   -- the tally table
as
(
    select n = 0
    union all
    select n = n + 1
    from   numbers
    where  n < 99
)
merge   Customer_Note as t
using
(
    select  Note_ID = case when n.n = 0 then Note_ID
                               else @last_id + row_number() over(order by Note_ID, n.n)
                               end, 
            Customer_ID, Note = substring(Note, n.n * @max_len + 1, @max_len)
    from    Customer_Note
            inner join numbers n on  n.n >= 0
                                and n.n < ceiling(len(Note) * 1.0 / @max_len)
    where   len(Note) > @max_len
) as s
on  s.Note_ID       = t.Note_ID
when    not matched by target
then
    insert ( Note_ID, Customer_ID, Note )
    values ( Note_ID, Customer_ID, Note )
when    matched
then
    update  set
            Note    = s.Note;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/g7K-eKeQ)